# Issues with heatmap visualization of melted dataframe in R

Tags: r

(Please let me know if I'm breaking any posting etiquette, as I haven't posted here before)

I'm trying to get a presentable heatmap of a dataframe I've melted. Each row of the original dataframe represents a different protein, and each column represents a different cell type (3 cell types with 3 mass spec shots each, so 9 columns total). The dataframe contains relative TMT intensity of each protein in each cell type.

I've melted the dataframe so that there are 3 columns: the first contains each proteins as an index of the original dataframe, the second contains cell and mass spec shot, and the third contains relative TMT abundance.

I'm trying to use ggplot to make a heatmap, and when I do, I keep getting very small lines inside the heatmap, with a mostly grey background. I've tried using both geom_tile() and geom_raster, but both give the same result. My dataframes (both original and melted) are summarized below, along with my code.

[Head of original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaLp2.png) (hclust.diff)

[Head of melted dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoqGG.png) (molten.diff)

Code:

```
molten.diff <- melt(as.matrix(hclust.diff))
names(molten.diff)[c(1:3)] <- c("Protein", "Cell", "value")

ggplot(data = molten.diff,
       aes(x = Cell, y = Protein, fill = value)) + 
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlBu") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

And the resulting [heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Wm0.png)

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like the protein IDs are interpreted as numbers, therefore they are represented as lines on the y axis. Try `y = as.character(Protein)` in the `aes` statement.

Comment: @user727089 that did the trick. Thanks a ton!